# establishing trust between 2 domains

Tags: domain, trusted-domain

I have Domain X and M. There are SharePoint farm on respected domain. Last night they open the firewall and now I can add X\domain users to M domain farm and visa-versa.

When I go to domain X farm and type http://domainx.sharepoint.com i get nothing but i can ping the servers by name and servers ip (like wfe, app servers etc.).

When I go to domain M farm http://domainM.sharepoint.com from domain X computers I get challenged for user id and password (normal) but then I get access denied even after adding X\Domain users to visitor group.

Any idea how to go by fixing this issue.

ps: Site permisssions does see domain users from both Domain.